# Observers in General Relativity: do transformations happen between two different observers or between two local coordinates both of the same observer?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, observers

In my understanding of general relativity, I am a little confused. Could someone please clarify this:

Given the definition of a manifold with its collection of subsets(patches) and mapping functions, are these different subsets (and thus corresponding different local coordinates) meant to indicate one single observer whose vision of the manifold is the collection of those subsets and mapping functions?

Or is it that different patches along with their local coordinates refer to different observers?

In other words, *is the transformation of the physical quantity(any tensor) from one set of local coordinates, a transformation from one observer to another observer?  Or that this transformation is being made between the tensor which the same observer is observing but in different coordinates?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, really. Coordinates are, in general, not directly related to the experience of any observer at all, and not recognizing this this is a source of great confusion among students (and even the occasional expert).

When you watch an airplane flying overhead, it is tempting to imagine that you are observing the airplane directly - but that's not really true. You are just a passive receiver of the light which is being *emitted* from the airplane, which has to travel a fairly long distance through the air in order to reach you. Asking about what a generic human observer would see with their generic human eyes is really asking a question not just about how an object moves through space, but also how the light being emitted from that object reaches them, and the latter is typically not encoded into a choice of coordinates.

A coordinate system is nothing more or less than an unambiguous way to smoothly assign numerical labels to events (by which I mean, points in spacetime).  In Newtonian physics (assuming $c\rightarrow \infty$), a description in terms of Cartesian coordinates is readily translatable in an intuitive way into the experience of a human observer at the (spatial) coordinate origin.  Given a finite speed of light (i.e. special relativity), we need to take care when we translate events into the observer's experience (see e.g. length contraction vs [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation)).  In general relativity where Cartesian coordinates typically don't exist, we have to be much *more* careful, and generic coordinate systems are even further removed from the observations of a human observer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand that coordinates are just numerical labels to events. I have another request:.   Referring to:. " *how the light being emitted from that object reaches them is typically not encoded into a choice of coordinates.* "  Could you please give me the mention of a source where I can read an example which shows how an observer in a non uniform motion would find the expression of the time coordinate of a point present in his light cone. I think I know the process, he sends and receives light, but I am looking for a specific example of the expression .

Comment: @GauravAnand Well, it doesn't really make sense to say that an observer *finds* the time coordinate of an event; they can assign an event any coordinates they like. However, if I understand the spirit of your question, you may be interested in [radar coordinates](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0412024).

Comment: Thanks again, this source will be very helpful for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The term "observer" is just a verbal shorthand and it means whatever the author wants it to mean. It has no explicit part in the math or in the theory. Some authors will refer to an identified worldline as an observer, other authors will refer to a coordinate chart, and still others will use different meanings that they may not even explicitly describe.

Coordinate transformations map from one coordinate chart to another coordinate chart. Each chart is, by definition, a smooth invertible mapping between an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an open set in the manifold. Because the mapping is invertible you can map from one chart to the manifold and then to another chart. This is a coordinate transform between the two charts.

Neither the charts nor the transformations are explicitly linked to any concept of an observer, which as I said earlier is not really an explicit part of the theory or the math anyway.